# plot with different order matrix in a function

Tags: matlab, function, math, mat

I want to plot  **E(on x-axis) vs f(on y-axis)** for different VAlues of **T** but it show matrix not of same order. How to plot for **T = 100,125,150,175,200,...,500** and plot with **different color** with **linewidth thicker** than normal say 2.
**Although i am getting the result when i put single value of T.** But i need to know how to plot by for multiple value of T simultaneously and **values of E = 0 to 10 are common to all T**

````
format long
k = 1.38*1e-21;
e = 1.6*1e-19;
E = (0:0.1:9)*e;

Ef = 5*e;
T=100:25:200;
x=1/(k*T);
f = 1./(exp((E - Ef)*x) + 1); %% fermi function
plot(E,f,'r','LineWidth',2)
legend({'T=100'})
hold on
plot(Ef,0.5,'o','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','blue',...
    'MarkerEdgeColor','black')```
````

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, your previous questions seem to have received good answers. Please consider taking a look back to mark the helpful answers that solve your problem as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) in each question of yours by clicking `✔` on the left of the answers.You can also [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/) the helpful answers by clicking `▲` on the left of the answers. This will give the volunteers some reward that they deserve for spending their time on your problems. If those answers don't solve your problem, please comment under the answers to explain it

Answer (score 3):

You need implicit expansion to find all those values of `f` in one-go.

```
x = 1./(k*T);  % ./ for element-wise division

f = 1./ (exp((E-Ef) .*  x.') + 1); % fermi function
%  implicit-expansion^    ^fixing dimension order
%         
% In <= R2016a, use bsxfun for implicit expansion as follows:
% f = 1./(exp(bsxfun(@times,E-Ef,x.')) + 1);

%Plotting the results
plot(E,f,'LineWidth',2);  %Don't hard-code red color here if you need different colors
hold on;
plot(Ef,0.5,'o','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','b','MarkerEdgeColor','k');
legend("T="+T); 
%In older versions without string data type, you can create your legend like this: 
%legend(cellstr(strcat('T=',num2str(T.'))));
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @ Sardar Usama Sir can you please explain how you fixed the dimension order, since E is or order 91 and x is of order 5. I means you had used .* For matrix multiplication and .' for transpose so how it could happen for two different dimensions of matrices.

Comment: Sir, your result are absolutely perfect but I need understand, I am a new user to matlab. When 91×1 and 1×5 it will give 91×5 matrix but  I am confuse here in the plot the data with mix in five column so how did matlab will recognise whether what to plot.

Comment: That's called implicit expansion. `.*` means element-wise multiplication when the order of two matrices is same. If it's not same then the array is broadcasted first before element-wise multiplication. For your case, this is the same as `repmat(E-Ef,5,1).' .* repmat(x,91,1)`. i.e.  `E-Ef` is `1*91` . It is broadcasted as `5*91` i.e. the array is copied to 5 times in new rows. `x` is `1*5`, the array is copied to 91 times to get `91*5` array and then you can fix the order with the transpose before element-wise multiplication. For more, read this: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/m

Comment: @ Sardar Usama Thank you sir